# Installed vsftpd in my Ubuntu machine, but wasn't asked for admin password?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I just installed vsftpd on my Turnkey Linux virtual machine and I can connect to it, a prompt is displayed asking me for my password.

What is the default username/password for vsftpd?

I also enabled anonymous usage in etc/vsftpd.conf but it's still asking me to enter a password when I try to login using "anonymous" as my username.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you also turn on the `no_anon_password=YES` setting in vsftpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have anonymous enable in vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=YES
```

If this is enable & anonymous is not working, Check if selinux is not blocking it.

```
# setenforce 0
```

There can be numerous issues with vsftp & selinux in regard of home directory, ftp connecting to database for authentication.

Try to login with ftp as username & password.